# Unit-testing mail sending with postal and moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, postal

`System.ArgumentNullException` is thrown from `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities` constructor when `mail.Send()` from test called. It requires `httpBrowserCapabilities` parameter.

Code I have used:

EmailModel:

```
public class EmailModel :Email
{
    public EmailModel() :base("EmailModel")
    {

    }
    public string To = "**********@gmail.com";

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_NameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resource), Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_EmailRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [RegularExpression(".+@.+", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_EmailWrong", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "Topic")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_TopicRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string Topic { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "Massage")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_MassageRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string Massage { get; set; }
}
```

View of message:

```
@model *******.Models.EmailModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
To: @Model.To
Subject: @Model.Topic

The massage from @Model.Name @Model.Email
Massage text:
@Model.Massage
```

UnitTest :

```
public class EmailSetter
{
    public const string DefaultName = "NameTest";
    public const string DefaultEmail = "EmailTest@domaintest.test";
    public const string DefaultTopic = "TopicTest";
    public const string DefaultMassage = "Massage test.";
    public EmailModel GetEmail(string Name = DefaultName, string Topic = DefaultTopic, string Email = DefaultEmail, string Massage = DefaultMassage)
    {
        EmailModel email = new EmailModel();
        email.Name = Name;
        email.Topic = Topic;
        email.Email = Email;
        email.Massage = Massage;
        return email;
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class MailTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MailSendWithRightModel()
    {
        //Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        Mock<EmailModel> email = new Mock<EmailModel>();
        email.Object.Name = EmailSetter.DefaultName;
        email.Object.Email = EmailSetter.DefaultName;
        email.Object.Topic = EmailSetter.DefaultTopic;
        email.Object.Massage = EmailSetter.DefaultMassage;
        //Act
        controller.Contact(email.Object);
        //Assert
        email.Verify(mail => mail.Send());
    }
}
```

Controller from test:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Contact(EmailModel emailModel)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Send = true;
        emailModel.Send();
        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    return View(emailModel);
}
```

What I have tried (in unit test method):

1. creating `new HttpBrowserCapabilities` through `new
       BrowserCapabilitiesFactory`
2. creating `new
       HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper` with `HttpBrowserCapabilities`
       object

Any ideas how to make code not to throw exception? (i.e. make current HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper get existing HttpBrowserCapabilities) :)

Comment: You have made several statements. But what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to send an actual email (integration test) or was the intention to mock the sending of the email? Most probably Email is trying to send an email but the proper dependencies have not been configured for the test.

Comment: I'm trying to test if Send method will be called, if right model is given to the controller. I too think that problem is in dependencies that are created during normal application startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [Postal Unit Testing](http://aboutcode.net/postal/unit-testing.html)

> When unit testing code that uses Postal, you may want to verify that
>   an email would be sent, without actual sending it.
>
> Postal provides an interface `IEmailService` and an implementation,
>   `EmailService`, which actually sends email.
>
> Assuming you use some kind of IoC container, configure it to inject an
>   `IEmailService` into your controller.
>
> Then use the service to send email objects (instead of calling
>   `Email.Send()`).

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    readonly IEmailService emailService;

    public HomeController(IEmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Contact(EmailModel email) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            emailService.Send(email);
            ViewBag.Send = true;
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        return View(email);
    }
}
```

> Test this controller by creating a mock of the `IEmailService`
>   interface.

```
[TestClass]
public class MailTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MailSendWithRightModel() {
        //Arrange
        var mockService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
        var controller = new HomeController(mockService.Object);
        var email = new EmailSetter().GetEmail();

        //Act
        controller.Contact(email);

        //Assert
        mockService.Verify(m => m.Send(email));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I should have read the documentation better. If someone will use my code and this answer code: var email = EmailSetter.GetEmail(); should be changed to EmailModel email = (new EmailSetter()).GetEmail();

Comment: Thought is was a static factory method. fixed.